# Problems when compiling and running a simple Maven project with Spring in JDeveloper 12c

Tags: spring, maven, jdeveloper

I'm trying to compile and run the first examples of the book "Beginning Spring" in JDeveloper but I'm running with some issues.

Here's the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.wiley.beginningspring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-book-ch2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>spring-book-ch2</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <repositories/>
  <pluginRepositories/>
</project>
```

JDeveloper marks the following imports with errors of package not found:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
```

Of course I can't compile the project since those errors are present.

I've already installed Spring integration in the Updates menu.

In Netbeans 8 and Spring Tool Suite the project marks no errors and compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Those errors imply that JDeveloper isn't picking up the dependencies you list in your `pom.xml` file (or it's picking them up, but is unable to locate the corresponding JAR file).  Perhaps try reimporting the project into JDeveloper using the instructions [found here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/maven11g-090173.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've reimported the project with the doc's instructions but I'm still getting the same errors. I've tried also creating another application and reimporting the project. When clicking on "Show Classpath" the spring-context jar appears on the list.

Comment: What about the 'spring-beans' JAR file?  Does that appear as well?  The 'spring-context' JAR does not contain the annotation classes that your compiler is complaining about.  Those are contained in a [different JAR file](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.5.RELEASE), which _should_ be getting included on the classpath automatically as a dependency of the 'spring-context' JAR.  Perhaps the dependency isn't being resolved by Maven/JDeveloper.

Comment: I think that might be the problem, adding manually the dependency in the POM file solves the compilation errors from the annotations, but other errors remain that I guess are also from non-resolved dependencies. Is there a way to solve or troubleshoot this?

Comment: Should be.  Have you changed any of Maven's settings from their default values?  It might be worth checking to make sure that JDeveloper is looking in the right place for your local Maven repository.

Comment: Yes, I haven't moved the default values, actually in the repository section it's pointing directly to the folder used by both NetBeans and Eclipse: ~/.m2.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks but I think this is a partial solution since other errors remain. I think the cause is what aroth says about JDeveloper not resolving properly the Maven dependencies.